# Problems of routes in own package- Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a laravel package and I have added routes, views, migrations, etc. and I have linked it to my project. Up to here everything is correct, but authentication is not working, the only thing I have done has been to generate the authentication routes as in a normal laravel project and I have added it to the group of routes in the following way:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\http\Request;

//That file is the package's web.php

Route::group(['namespace'=>'myPackage\Blog\Http\Controllers', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('blog','BlogController@index')->name('blog');
    Route::post('blog', 'BlogController@send');


    Route::get('administrador', 'adminController@index')->name('administrador');
});
```

and that is my package's serviceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace Tetres\Blog;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class BlogServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{


    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/routes/web.php');
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/views', 'blog');
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/database/migrations');
    }

    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```

simply by adding `'middleware' => 'auth'`, these routes stop working, some idea of ​​what I should do? Thank you!

Comment: Can you specify the error you get when you include the auth?

Comment: @AlvaroAlves nothing, just don't load the page

Comment: did you login ?

Comment: @HasanTıngır 
When login starts trying to load but does not finish loading

Comment: is it happening at all routes (need authentication ones)?

Comment: @HasanTıngır Yes, just occurring in the routes with authentication, but only in the packet, the routes that are not from the packet and have authentication work correctly

Comment: I have added my servideProvider too in case it's helpful @HasanTıngır

Comment: do you have any problem with storing sessions ?

Comment: you probably want the 'web' group of middleware to have sessions for auth

Comment: try @lagbox's suggestion, I think `web` group middleware is not being applied to your routes since it is not originally part of `routes/web.php`

Comment: @lagbox I dont understand exactly what you mean, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing the same problem. Expanding on @lagbox,

Add `$this->middleware("web");` next to where you normally indicate `$this->middleware("auth");`

An example of how you will do it in the `__construct()` of your controller.

```
class my_controller extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware("web");  // this will solve your problem
        $this->middleware("auth");      
    }
    ...
}
```

In your case, add `'web'` to your middleware:

```
//That file is the package's web.php

Route::group(['namespace'=>'myPackage\Blog\Http\Controllers', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function(){
    Route::get('blog','BlogController@index')->name('blog');
    Route::post('blog', 'BlogController@send');


    Route::get('administrador', 'adminController@index')->name('administrador');
});
```