# Authentication sessions in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, session, authentication

I'm trying to implement a domain wide authentication (DWA) on top of the usual user authentication. The use case is prevent a work-in-progress site from leaking to google/public.

1. Created scaffolding code using `php artisan make:auth`
2. Log in via `/login` and is redirect to `/home` which shows the default `You are logged in!`
3. When I reload `/home`, I see that `$this->session->id` in `SessionGuard.php` has an ID value which I will refer to as A, the session also has 5 `attributes`.
4. Next, I insert the `auth` middleware into the route `/product/{id}` and load it
5. I see that `$this->session->id` in `SessionGuard.php` has a brand new ID with 0 `attributes`
6. This causes `authenticate()` in `Authenticate.php` middleware to throw an `Unauthenticated` exception and redirect me to `/login`
7. As the browser loads `/login`, `$this->session->id` in `SessionGuard.php` now shows the ID of A with the earlier 5 `attributes`
8. `/login` results in `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` middleware running and redirecting to `/home`
9. As a result of the DWA, I'm unable to load `/product/{id}`, it just keeps redirecting me to `/home`

My question is, why does #5 show a new session ID instead of A? 
Where and how is this ID derived in the first place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [Problems of routes in own package- Laravel 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52156701/problems-of-routes-in-own-package-laravel-5-6/53843343#53843343)

It was due to my controller having only the `auth` but lacking the `web` middleware. Hope it helps someone.